# What is the Codeigniter equivilent to PHP multi_query

Tags: php, codeigniter, multi-query

Whith PHP - I write a multi_query something like this:

```
$MySQL_string .= "UPDATE `table` SET `name` = 'joe' WHERE `ID` = '1'";
$MySQL_string .= "UPDATE `table` SET `name` = 'Jane' WHERE `ID` = '2'";

if($DB->mysqli->multi_query($MySQL_string) === TRUE){
    echo"Query executed successfully<BR>";
}else{
    echo"Error executing query: ".$DB->mysqli->error;
    die();
}
```

What is the equivalent to PHP's multi_query() in Codeigniter?

If there is no equivilent - how would I use multi_query() in Codeigniter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Codeigniter function `$this->db->update_batch()`, to which you can pass either an array or object.

To complete your example it could look like this:

```
$data = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Joe' ,
    'ID' => '1'
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Jane' ,
    'ID' => '2'
  )
);
```

and then use:

```
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'ID');
```

more info [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data):

Comment: I see. The 'ID' in the batch statement acts as WHERE `ID` = '2' etc.
And the batch uses WHEN `ID` = '2' THEN etc... Brilliant... I think 0_o 
I wonder how this compares in speed to PHP multi_query() and I wonder why Codeigniter did not include multi_query() as part of its query builders?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use transactions?

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

[CodeIgniter’s Approach to Transactions](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)

Comment: Not sure I understand - why would I need a transaction?
There would be no need to roll anything back in my case.

Comment: transactions : for half run queries .

Comment: Thank you  - but there is no need for a transaction here. Unless that is the only option in Codeignter for multi_query(). I am just looking for the equivalent to multi_query()