# How to use batch update/insert sql using codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, sql-update

in this example.. how can i simplified and fasten up the update and insert of data in the database?

```
//if count($arr_list['sample_element1'] is 500+++ or more records

$i =0;
while ($i < count($arr_list['sample_element1'])) {

$update_db= array('column1' => $arr_list['sample_element1'][$i],'column2' => $arr_list['sample_element2'][$i]);

$this->db->update('sample_table',$update_db);

$i++;
}
```

if the record to be save is over 1000 data...it will take about sometime to finish the process.. thank in advance.. =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599703/what-is-the-codeigniter-equivilent-to-php-multi-query/41600560#41600560

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [batch_update](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

```
$this->db->update(table_name,array,where_key_word);
```

here **table_name** = your table name

and **array** = an array containing multiple associative array

and **where_key_word** = the column which should be used in where condition

also read [this question thread for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465604/how-to-perform-a-batch-update-using-codeigniter-arrays)

batch updating thousands of element together may create performance issue.Better split them up and update by smaller batch.Also use transactions so that if any of the update fails the whole update procedure can be rolled back

Answer (score 0):

Taking @AL-zami's answer you're looking for this

```
$data = [];
$this->db->trans_start();
foreach($arr_list as $item)
{
    $data[] = [
        'column1' => $item['element1'],
        'column2' => $item['element2'],
        'column3' => $item['element3']
    ];
}
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'column1');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

Where 'column1' is the column used for the "WHERE" condition.

Comment: yes yes.. i have the same idea... but what if you have two or more where clause? do i have to add another parameter like this?   $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'column1','column2','column3');

Comment: No, that won't work. `update_batch()` won't accept that. Try using another `$this->db->where('field', $value)` call. But I don't think that will work..